# Item list added by "Page_alter" disappear

Tags: forms, ajax, uri

I added a list item by HOOK_form and HOOK_page_alter. After cache cleaning, the list appeared and it did the job but when i changed page, this list disappeared for no reason. She never returned on any pages. To solve that i need to clean the cache again...

My url :    *homeproject?projet=3737*

My code :

```
function header_eltmission_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $elmissionvalues['AVC'] = "Avant-Contrat";
    $idPjt = $_REQUEST['projet'];
    //Get the missions of the project
    $mission = _getElementMissionNode_ByPjt($idPjt);

    if(isset($mission)){
      foreach ($mission as $value) {
        $elmissionvalues[t($value->title)] = t($value->title);
      }
    }

    $form = array();
    $form['list_eltmission'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#attributes' => array('name' => array('list_eltmission')),
      '#prefix' => '<div class=\'block block-block contextual-links-region\'>',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#validated' => TRUE,
      '#options' => array_unique($elmissionvalues),
      '#ajax' => array(
         // 'callback' is a function that will be called when this element changes.
         'callback' => 'header_eltmission_callback',
         // 'wrapper' is the HTML id of the page element that will be replaced.
         'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
      ),
    );

    return $form;
}

function header_eltmission_callback($form, $form_state) {
     $valeur = $form_state['values']['list_eltmission'];
     $idPjt = str_replace("/homeproject?projet=", "", $form['#action']);

     $node = node_load($idPjt);
    $node->field_pjt_element_de_mission = array('und'=>array(array('value'=>$valeur)));
    node_save($node);

}

function header_eltmission_page_alter(&$page) {
    if(current_path() == 'homeproject') {

    $liste = array();
    $liste = drupal_get_form('header_eltmission_form');

    $page['header'] = array(
        '#weight' => -10,
        '#markup' => drupal_render($liste),
    );
  }
}
```

Someone got this problem ? How can i solve this please ?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean it won't appear on a different path? or a different projet value of the same path?

Comment: Have you tried setting `$form_state` to a referential parameter in your callback function?: `&$form_state`, maybe `$form` as well?

Comment: I mean, it won't appear on different project value of the same path. To explain : I cleared the cache -> Saw the list in homeproject?projet=3737 -> I changed project to homeproject?projet=3738 and the list had disappeared. When i returned on homeproject?projet=3737 the list is disappeared too. And i need to clear the cache again... I don't understand your answer Darvanen.